# VirtualHost module to search and replace HTML website code before delivered to client

Tags: php, html, linux, apache, virtualhost

I want to replace inside VirtualHost `</body>` element with:

```
<!-- Piwik -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _paq = _paq || [];
  _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
  _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
  (function() {
    var u="//stats.mydomain.com/";
    _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
    _paq.push(['setSiteId', '1']);
    var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
  })();
</script>
<noscript><p><img src="//stats.mydomain.com/piwik.php?idsite=1" style="border:0;" alt="" /></p></noscript>
<!-- End Piwik Code --></body>
```

I need to do this inside VirtualHost section because I can't directly modify website code.

I was thinking about some apache modules like mod_substitute, mod_sed, mod_include.

I need to add this PIWIK statistics code into every page.

Is this good way? Which one of this mods will be best to do this? Or maybe there is another solution?

Comment: `mod_includes`. Others are to perform search-replace. Your requirement here isn't that.

Comment: I don't see how I can use to this `mod_include`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is solution with [mod_ext_filter](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ext_filter.html) which looks very powerful:

1. Enable Apache module:

   > ```
   > a2enmod ext_filter
   > ```
2. Inside Apache configuration file, within `VirtualHost` section, add filter definition:

   > ```
   > ExtFilterDefine my_html_filter mode=output intype=text/html cmd="/usr/bin/php5 /var/www/data/myfilter.php"
   > SetOutputFilter my_html_filter
   > ```

   - `ExtFilterDefine` - this directive defines filter
   - `my_html_filter` - it's our filter name
   - `mode=output` - tells Apache to process the response
   - `intype=text/html` - specifies the MIME type of documents which should be filtered
   - `cmd="/usr/bin/php5 /var/www/data/myfilter.php"` - specifies the external command to run
   - `SetOutputFilter` - this directive activates filter
3. Content of PHP file `/var/www/data/myfilter.php`:

   > ```
   > <?php
   >
   > $stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
   > while($line = fgets($stdin)){
   >  $line = str_replace('</body>',"
   > <!-- Piwik -->
   > <script type='text/javascript'>
   >   var _paq = _paq || [];
   >   _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
   >   _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
   >   (function() {
   >     var u='//stats.mydomain.com/';
   >     _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
   >     _paq.push(['setSiteId', '1']);
   >     var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   >     g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
   >   })();
   > </script>
   > <noscript><p><img src='//stats.mydomain.com/piwik.php?idsite=1' style='border:0;' alt='' /></p></noscript>
   > <!-- End Piwik Code -->
   > </body>", $line);
   >
   >  echo $line;
   > }
   > fclose( $stdin );
   >
   > ?>
   > ```
4. Restart Apache:

   > ```
   > service apache2 restart
   > ```